# React, FastAPI, nginx not working when add `--root-path /api` to FastAPI

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, axios, fastapi

I have react & FastAPI being served with `nginx` using `docker`. When I run `docker-compose up`, everything works with the react app available at `localhost:3000` and api available at `localhost:8000`. For instance, the get request `localhost:8000/fleets/` returns the desired result. I would like the api to be reached at `localhost:3000/api/` instead though.

When I add `--root-path /api` to the FastAPI `Dockerfile`, the react app still loads at `localhost:3000` and I am able to reach the api at `localhost:3000/api/`, but my react app gets 404 errors when it tries to query for the api. When I go to the Network on tab in Chrome I see react queries for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fleets/` leading to a 404 error. The api still available at `localhoost:8000/fleets/` though.

[image]

**Should my react app be querying at `localhost:3000/api/` or `localhost:8000` and how do I make this adjustment?**

Note I am using `axios` but changing `axios.defaults.baseURL` doesn't appear to make an impact. I currently have `axios.defaults.baseURL = '/';` in my react `App.jsx`.

I have also removed `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3000"` from my react `package.json`.
In FastAPI, I have `origins = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:8000"]` for dealing with CORS.

FastAPI `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /api
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

react `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15.13-alpine
WORKDIR /react
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build
```

`nginx-setup.conf`:

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        root /var/www/react;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./api
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --root-path /api
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./react
    volumes:
      - react_build:/react/build

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx-setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - react_build:/var/www/react
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  react_build:
```

---

**EDIT** (for more details)

When running without the `--root-path /api`:

- `localhost:3000/api/fleets/` does actually work.
- `localhost:3000/api/fleets` gets redirected to `localhost:3000/fleets/` which gives nginx 404
- `localhost:3000/api/docs` gives `Failed to load API definition` error.
- `localhost:8000/docs` works.
- `localhost:8000/fleets/` works.
- `localhost:8000/fleets` gets redirected to `localhost:8000/fleets/` and works.
- React app pings `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fleets` and gets redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fleets/` which works.

When running with `--root-path /api`:

- `localhost:3000/api/fleets/` works
- `localhost:3000/api/fleets` gets redirected to `localhost:3000/api/fleets/` and works
- `localhost:3000/api/docs` works
- `localhost:8000/docs` gives Failed to Load API definition error.
- `http://localhost:8000/fleets/` works.
- `http://localhost:8000/fleets` gets redirected to `localhost:8000/api/fleets/ and gives` FastAPI`404`{"detail": "Not Found"}`

**EDIT** Here's a bare-bones reproducible example:

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── app
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.css
│   │   ├── App.jsx
│   │   ├── App.test.js
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── reportWebVitals.js
│   │   └── setupTests.js
│   └── yarn.lock
├── nginx
    └── nginx-setup.conf
```

`./backend/app/main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/day", tags=["Dates"])
async def get_day_of_week(day_num: int = 0):
    """
    Get the current day of week
    """
    days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    return days[day_num]
```

`./backend/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /alpine
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

`./backend/requirements.txt`

```
anyio==3.6.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
fastapi==0.78.0
h11==0.13.0
idna==3.3
pydantic==1.9.1
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.19.1
typing_extensions==4.3.0
uvicorn==0.18.2
```

`./frontend/src/App.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null); 
  const [day, setDay] = useState('Sun');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/day?day_num=3')
    .then((res) => setDay(res.data))
    .catch((err) => setError(err.message))
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <>Hello</>
    <>{day}{error}</>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`./frontend/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:15.13-alpine
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build
```

`./frontend/.dockerignore`

```
#node_modules
build
```

`./frontend/package.json`

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
      "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
      "axios": "^0.27.2",
      "react": "^17.0.2",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
      "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
      "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
  }
```

`./nginx/nginx-setup.conf`

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        root /var/www/react;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --root-path /api
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - react_build:/frontend/build

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
     - 3000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx-setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - react_build:/var/www/react
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
volumes:
  react_build:
```

Comment: How are you configuring the API endpoint in your react app? Usually you'll want to configure the other API URL base when building, so that your app in production requests content from `https://<prodhost>/api` - `<prodhost>` seems to be `localhost:3000` here (and `http`, not `https` probably)

Comment: @MatsLindh if I set `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';` and then query `axios.get('/fleets/')` I still see the react app first query `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fleets` and get 307, temporary redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fleets/` which returns 404 not found.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal, doesn't the `upstream` block provide the port?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing things up, how usually this is done:

You have your backend app (FastAPI) running on some port, let it be: `localhost:8000`

You have your frontend app (React) running on some port, let it be:
`localhost:3000`

Also, you use Nginx, so the route is: frontend -> nginx -> backend

> Should my react app be querying at localhost:3000/api/ or
> localhost:8000 and how do I make this adjustment?

Nether. Your *right* address to make queries is `http://localhost:8080/api/` (you proxy all your request through Nginx), this instruction `location /api/` means that all request to `localhost:8080/api/` will be proxied to `localhost:8000`, for production you'd specify port 80 and configure SSL.

I don't see the whole picture because of the absence of code, but I guess `--root-path` is not what you want. Also carefully check your ports in docker-compose, your app (frontend) must use only 8080 port, do not expose 8000.

Comment: I have added the code to recreate a bare-bones version of the issue if helpful. When I switch `fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/day?day_num=3`) to `fetch('http:localhost:8080/api/day?day_num=3')` as you suggested, I still get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: You've missed // in the second fetch

Comment: Can you create a repo with the code you've pasted here?

Comment: The second fetch missing // was just a typo in the comment. Here's repo: https://github.com/carter-page/demo-docker-nginx-fastapi-react.git

Answer (score 0):

## A possible approach to the problem!

### Disclaimer I

I don't know how much of [server side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) you need so I shall assume that you need the least. You can learn about Server side rendering and [Static Site Generation](https://www.techighness.com/post/static-site-and-static-site-generator-ssg/) at those links I've mentioned.

In a nutshell, server side rendering is basically a web page being rendered every time an user loads it. Where as SSG is an approach through which you usually pre-build pages and keep it ready.

### Disclaimer II:

**Your page doesn't change with your SSG content**

Now coming to addressing the problem, you can choose to build your react app using the build script. The command for that is

```bash
npx react-scripts build
```

Now once done, you can use this [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) documentation to serve the built static file. You need to configure your nginx and fastapi accordingly!

### Solution to SSR's

This is a tricky part, now you can choose to do one of these two options:

- You can choose to use implement a solution like [this](https://asperbrothers.com/blog/server-side-rendering-in-react/) where you can build a custom SSR solution.
- or you can choose to implement a SSR solution with NextJS where you can import your CRA components. These components will still work, and then you can choose to use [SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/streaming). This SSR solution will solve your API needs. Even [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/rendering-options/using-server-side-rendering/) with which you can build a similar solution.